# Secure communication across a LAN

Tags: delphi, encryption, network-protocols

I want to make a small app that collects data from a device attached to a serial port and passes it across a LAN to another app which stores it in a database.

I have done this already in one app on a single PC, so will effectively be splitting the app in half.

I have zer0 experience of network programming.

I want something "secure" meaning that the data are in some way encrypted and relatively straightforward to implement.

At the moment communication is one way, but I might want so send control data in the return direction later.

Can someone please recommend a protocol (preferably one which is commonly used for this sort of thing) and post a small code snippet of how to send and receive - let's say a data structure with a string for user name and an integer for age.

Or, just point me at a URL.

Thanks in advance.

---

Answer: I'm going with IpSec and [Exchanging Data over the Network using Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa112602a.htmhttp://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa112602a.htm)

Comment: Look at any of the Indy [demos](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/demos/index.en.aspx) for examples of communicating via TCP/IP or other protocols. The encryption part is a totally different question.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Ken, I will. This may be the first time forme, but not for others. I just wondered what tehy used (maybe I will look at Dr. Bob)

Comment: Sounds like a good approach for TCP/IP with SSL layer. Unfortunately the link on the demos page is dead and has been moved [here](http://adg.bmpcoe.org/download/indyssl/index.html). Note that you will also need the OpenSSL library for it (from [here](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) for instance).

Comment: the Indy demos seem to be unavailable :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use IPSec between the two computer and the operating system will encrypt the channel without any need of changing the applications.
Other option may be DCOM (if you use the Enterprise version of Delphi Datasnap supports it) that can also encrypt the communication (must be set in the configuration, works best in a domain).
Both options don't need certificates or the like, and the OS will take care of storing the keys safely.

Comment: + 1 Thanks for taking the time to reply. I don't have the Enterprise version , ala$$$$$. Do you have a URL for a code example of IPsec?

Comment: IPSec doesn't require coding. It requires to setup both PC OSes to communicate via IPSec. See for example here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb531150. Once configured properly, the applications will communicate over a protected channel handled by the OS itself, not the application. From the application perspective nothing changes and no code is needed.

Comment: +1, IPSec sounds good (even if network configuration is for me a nightmare :)

Comment: The difference is that IPSec is a NIC to NIC protected channel. If you need a full end-to-end (meaning application to application) protection IPSec could not be enough. With IPSec if you can intercept the traffic before it goes to the network layer you could still intercept it. On the other way it is a robust standard solution that can take advantage of OS and network features (i.e. kerberos in a domain). Of course only you know what is best for your application and what are the security requirements.

Comment: +1 for both comments. This is sounding very good. I am not paranoid, and both PCs are the responsibility of whoever uses my app. They tend to be non-tech, but might just know enough to ask if I am "keeping the data secret from the internets".  I will look at the MS page (and hope that it doesn't require .NET (although I can live with that if I must)).  Thanks again!

Comment: Btw, if IPsec transparently encrypts the data, do you have an example of how my app sends/receives data, ignoring IpSec?

Comment: IPSec encrypts network packets at the network layer (it's alike a VPN, although a VPN has other features, and it could use IPSec at the transport layer). Once you configure IPSec, every network packet matching the rules will be automatically encrypted, but both client and server applications won't be aware of that, it's handled by the OS network stack. From the applications point of view, nothing changes.